# How reliable is Arduino Uno Serial, via USB (ATmega16U2), CRC needed?

Tags: serial, atmega328, atmega16u2, reliability

I have a question about the reliability of Serial communication, i.e. in particular if I need to implement CRC/checksum/ECC because of bit transmission errors?
I

I however think there is no general answer as there are different ways in which serial communication with the Arduino Uno's Atmega328P chip might work.

- (a) The serial communication is between two Atmega328P Chips, and using rather long wires
- (b) The serial communication is between two Atmega328P Chips, and using rather short wires
- (c) The serial communication is between one Atmega328P and the ATmega16U2, who picks up and forwards the signals via USB protocol (e.g. to a PC)

My question is with regard to the ATmega16U2. The distance (wire/line length) on the Arduino R3 board is about 2cm/1" tops, which I expect to reduce the likeliness that a signal will become corrupted. 
Assuming that the USB protocol which is further employed to transport the signal by itself provides by itself an ECC/CRC/checksums, I wonder if it is not rather superflous to implement a CRC when receving and sending messages via the serial communication in the case (c), while I however expect it to be *more* necessary for (b) and almost certainly necessary for (c).

Also, if this matters to respond to the question, I was wondering if the power supply (i.e. if Arduino Uno is powered by the USB provided voltage of ~4.5V or rather via an external 12V power adapter) would have an impact on the "corruptability" of the signals on the TX/RX serial lines?

Comment: UART already has parity bit in the protocol, though the Arduino doesn't use it. It might be more useful to do some kind of checksum on a higher level protocol, on top of UART.

Comment: for a crypto box project, i used thumbtacks as uart contacts. I transferred 2kb keys with CRCs at 115200.  In testing ~1200 keys, I only once had to resend once because of a CRC mismatch, and i think that was because the thumbtacks stopped touching as i plopped down into my desk setup...

Answer (score 1):

If you use the appropriate buffering of the 0/5V signal over the long wires, case A, no error detection and correction is needed. RS232, RS485, your data will be just fine (can be up to thousands of feet).

Shorter wires, from Atmega device to Atmega device, I've neved had to use anything, even at 115200 speeds, case B, case C.

16U2 to PC, that will depend on the quality of the USB cable. The +/-3V differential signal (similar to RS485 levels) is quite high speed, like 4 Mbits/second, so you want a good cable with good shielding.